# Can we have an array of custom modules?

Tags: verilog

Can we have an array of instances for a custom module?

For example: we can have `input [15:0] a;` - this creates a bus. Can we do same thing for custom modules, i.e. `DFF [15:0] d;`, where DFF is a custom module?
Here I intend to create 16 instances of the DFF module.

Answer (score 30):

Verilog arrays of instances were added in Verilog-1995 (IEEE 1364-1995).  They can be used with gates, user-defined primitives, and modules.  Generates, which are more powerful but also more complex, were added in Verilog-2001.

Here is an example array of module instances:

```
DFF d[15:0] (clk, DFF_i, DFF_o);
```

For each port connection, if the size matches that of the formal parameter then it is connected to every instance.  Otherwise each instance is connected to a part-select (or bit-select) of the expression.

Comment: Are these modules instantiated parallelly or one after other?

Comment: @eldos: If the size of a port connection matches that of the formal parameter then it is connected in parallel to every instance.  Using a vector you can connect the instances in serial.

Comment: @mark4o Do these kind of instantiations work properly as expected ? `DFF d[15:0] (clk, DFF[15:0], DFF[16:1]);`

Comment: @eldos: sure, except you'll need to use different names for the module and the vector

Answer (score 11):

it is not possible to do this directly (*update*: now after mark4o's answer I know that there is a way), but what you can do is using the `generate` statement to create multiple instances of your custom module and hook them up to your signals. Should look something like this:

```
wire DFF_i[15:0];
wire DFF_o[15:0];

generate
  genvar i;
  for (i=0; i<15; i=i+1) begin : dff
    custom i_custom(
       .clk(clk)
      ,.input(DFF_i[i])
      ,.output(DFF_o[i])
      );
  end
endgenerate
```

Otherwise there are probably some possibility during synthesis to use the correct custom modules, but I'm not an expert there.

Cheers,
Daniel