# How to change ordered port list into named port list in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

Now I'm trying to implement systemverilog tutorial [here](http://www.testbench.in/SL_04_PHASE_1_TOP.html),

Especially, I am referring the switch tutorial of SystemVerilog.

If you view the code, they are used ordered port list in testcase TC(mem_intf, input_intf, output_intf[4]); but I want to change them to named port list.
Does anyone know how to change into a named ordered port list from ordered port list in SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be **four** different types of port connections in SytemVerilog as follows:

(1) Using **positional port connections**. The one shown in your link code. The ports are **mapped as per position** in the instantiated module.

(2) Using **named port connections**. This is a *verbose* declaration. The position of ports does not matter. An example can be as follows. Note that the position can now be **interchanged**.

```
mymodule u1 (.data(data), .address(address));
// Is same as follows:
mymodule u1 (.address(address), .data(data));
```

(3) Using new SystemVerilog **.name** **implicit port connections**. Whenever the **port name and size matches** the connecting net or bus name and size, the ports get connected. This is not a widely used technique.

```
// Searches for address and data sized variables in current module
mymodule u1 (.address, .data);
```

(4) Using new SystemVerilog **.*** implicit port connections**. whenever the port **name and size matches** the connecting net or bus name and size, the ports are connected.

```
reg [2:0] address;
reg [15:0] data;
// Connect address data automatically. Provided the name is same.
mymodule u1 (.*);
```

So, in your case, the following are **equivalent**. Since the name of interface instances like `input_intf`, `output_intf`, and `mem_intf` are same, the `.*` connection shall also work.

```
testcase TC (.mem_intf(mem_intf),.input_intf(input_intf),.output_intf(output_intf));

testcase TC (.output_intf(output_intf),.mem_intf(mem_intf),.input_intf(input_intf));

testcase TC (.*);
```

For more information, refer to [CummingsDesignCon2005_SystemVerilog_ImplicitPorts](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsDesignCon2005_SystemVerilog_ImplicitPorts.pdf) paper.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask you one more thing with off the topic? Why  are they using testcase TC (mem_intf,input_intf,output_intf);    instead  testcase TC (mem_intf,input_intf,output_intf[4]); It is so confused, I can't understand it

Comment: It is an array of interface. Connecting `output_intf` means all 4 instances are connected. While connecting `output_intf[4]` only connects one interface instance. Hence **port width mismatch** shall occur. You can use `output_intf[3:0]` in order to explicitly define number of instances to be connected.

Comment: Thanks, is  'output_interface output_intf[4](Clock); 'and program testcase(mem_interface.MEM mem_intf,input_interface.IPinput_intf,output_interface.'OP output_intf[4]');  just meanning that only connects one interface instance? Then how to set to [0]~[3]?  Where does it declare? How do we know the output_itf is 4bits?

Comment: `output_interface output_intf[4](Clock);` creates **4 instances**. Its an array of instances. Refer [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378159/can-we-have-an-array-of-custom-modules) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify **named port connections** (I had a surprisingly hard time finding it on google): The syntax is like this:

```
mygate gate0(.pin1(wire1), .pin2(wire2))
```

where wires can be thought of as *outside* of the gate and pins *inside* or *part of* the gate.

This is analogous to [python named/keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments):

```
gate0(pin1=wire1, pin2=wire2)
```

However, unlike in python where arguments are passed in and the function returns a return value, in System Verilog ports may be *input*, *output*, or *inout*.

Further reading: http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece474/beamer_lectures/modules.pdf