# Verilog Module Instantiation Syntax Clarification

Tags: verilog

I've been looking at some verilog code and came across something I've never seen before and have not been able to find information about online.

```
module FA_n_bit(c_out, Sum, A, B, c_in);

parameter    word_size = 4;      // the default size of this n bit adder

input       [word_size-1:0]      A, B;
input                            c_in;

output      [word_size-1:0]       Sum;
output                          c_out;

wire        [word_size-1:0]   c_inner;

// the c_out of the ith 1-bit full aderr is the c_in of the (i+1)th full adder 
FA_one_bit  fullAdder [word_size-1:0](
  {c_out, c_inner[word_size-1:1]},
  Sum, 
  A,
  B,
  {c_inner[word_size-1:1], c_in}
);
```

endmodule

I understand the parameter syntax, but I am having a hard time understanding what the FA_one_bit fullAdder [word_size-1:0] (...) syntax does.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
So far I think that its declaring 4 fullAdders but I get lost at the concatenation of the c_out and c_inner[word_size-1:1].

Answer (score 1):

The `FA_one_bit` is another module instantiated inside `FA_n_bit` module. The instance name is `fullAdder`. Also, `[word_size-1:0]` indicates that `word_size` number of instances are created.

In Verilog, when you are **instantiating** a module, that means you are adding **extra hardware** to the board. Here, **4 fullAdders** are added.

**Concatenations** are expressed using the brace characters `{` and `}`, with commas separating the expressions within. Referring to SystemVerilog LRM [IEEE 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/ieee-1800-2012-systemverilog-published/), section 11.4.12:

> A concatenation is the result of the joining together of bits resulting from one or more expressions. The
>   concatenation shall be expressed using the brace characters { and }, with commas separating the expressions
>   within.

```
// if a, b and c are 8-bit numbers, the results has 24 bits
For Example: {a, b[3:0], c, 4'b1001}
```

Here, `{c_out, c_inner[word_size-1:1]}` means 1-bit of `c_out` and `word_size-1` bits of `c_inner` from MSB are concatenated. This shall result in a signal of width `word_size`.

Yet another example from LRM:

```
{a, b[3:0], w, 3'b101}
// equivalent to the following
{a, b[3], b[2], b[1], b[0], w, 1'b1, 1'b0, 1'b1}
```

The **MSB** of concatenated signal is `c_out` and **MSB-1** position is for `c_inner[word_size-1]` and **LSB** of signal is `c_inner[1]`.

For more information on array of instances, refer to [Array of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378159/can-we-have-an-array-of-custom-modules) link. Refer [IEEE 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/ieee-1800-2012-systemverilog-published/) section 11.4.12 for concatenation operator.