# Renaming bluespec modules programatically

Tags: bluespec

I have a module hierarchy and I want to generate verilog with a postfix to the module names. is there a way to do this at compile time ?

Example:

```
(*synthesize*)
module mk_abc(Empty);
```

Say I compile this 3 times, I want the generated verilog to be `mk_abc_1`, `mk_abc_2`, `mk_abc_3`. Can I somehow specify what the post-fix should be ? Is there a way to do this at compile time ? Or what is the best way to get this done?

Note: these modules (and their sub-modules) use ifdefs. The values for these compile-time macros (ifdefs) can change every time I compile. that is, `mk_abc_1`, `mk_abc_2`, and `mk_abc_3` can use three completely different set of values for the macros, but the names of the macros remain the same (they're the same module).

Thanks in advance.

I'm opening a question here, hoping to get a faster answer. I have also asked the same question [here](https://github.com/B-Lang-org/bsc/discussions/636).
I have no idea how to get started with this.

Comment: The two answers to this question should provide some ideas  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378159/can-we-have-an-array-of-custom-modules